# All Latin squares

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a way to find the number of a the distinct latin squares for a given $n$?

I've tried by brute force, and for $n=3$ we have

$$123, 231, 312, 123, 312, 231$$

and we get $6$ in total.
And so on by permuting the rows. But is there a fixed number, for, let's say, $n=8$?

Comment: Your list for $n=3$ is the orthogonal array representation, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square#Examples

Comment: There are $12$ squares for $n=3$ though?

Comment: The expression is $\prod_{i=1}^n (n-i)!$, for $n=8$ this is roughly $5\cdot10^{15}$.

Comment: @s.harp start from $i=0$ instead?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma oh yes damn, I had thought to disinclude $0!$ but then I should have decreased the upper indice or had the product be over $i!$

Comment: @s.harp disallowing $0!$ from a product is really not needed, as an extra 1 does not hurt.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, but if you write it out it looks like $3!\cdot 2!\cdot1!\cdot0!=6\cdot2\cdot1\cdot1$, I think it looks nicer as $3!\cdot2!\cdot1!=6\cdot2\cdot1$.